# Databinding: Using value in one XML node to look up another

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have XML that looks like this:

```
<showcases>
<showcase id="260">
<artistID>2143</artistID>
<venueID>29</venueID>
<startdatetime>2012-09-12 17:30:00</startdatetime>
<enddatetime>2012-09-12 18:00:00</enddatetime>
</showcase>
[etc]
</showcases>
```

And within the same XML file these:

```
<showcaseartists>
<showcaseartist id="2129">
[other stuff about them]
</showcaseartist>
[etc]
</showcaseartists>

<venue id="19">
<name> ... </name>
<address> ... </address>
[etc]
</venue>
```

How do I go about getting that data into a list?

So like this:

```
var showcasedata = from query in loadedData.Descendants("showcase")
select new Showcase
{
    StartDateTime = (DateTime)query.Element("startdatetime"),
    ArtistName = ????,
    Venue = ????
};
ShowcasesList.ItemsSource = showcasedata.ToList();
```

I figure there must be a way but I can't find it!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The quick and dirty way:

```cs
var showcasedata = from query in loadedData.Descendants("showcase")
select new Showcase
{
    StartDateTime = (DateTime)query.Element("startdatetime"),
    ArtistName = (string)loadedData.Elements("showcaseartist").First(e => (string)e.Attribute("id") == (string)query.Element("artistID"))
};
ShowcasesList.ItemsSource = showcasedata.ToList();
```

It should work on small XML documents, but you will quickly encounter performances issues on larger documents. For those, use a Dictionary for caching:

```cs
var artists = loadedData.Elements("showcaseartist").ToDictionary(e => (string)e.Attribute("id"), e => e);

var showcasedata = from query in loadedData.Descendants("showcase")
select new Showcase
{
    StartDateTime = (DateTime)query.Element("startdatetime"),
    ArtistName = (string)artists[(string)query.Attribute("id")].Element("artistID")
};
```

It would be even better to put an "Artist" object in the Dictionary rather than the XML node. Adapt the code to your model object however you can.

Answer (score 0):

Say your class looks like

```
public class Showcase
{
  public DateTime StartDateTime;
  public string ArtistName;
  public string Venue;
}
```

Try this

```
var showcasedata = 
  from query1 in loadedData.Descendants("showcase")
    select new Showcase() {
      StartDateTime = (DateTime)query1.Element( "startdatetime" ),
      ArtistName = ( from query2 in loadedData.Descendants("showcaseartist")
                     where (int)query1.Element( "artistID" ) == (int)query2.Attribute("id")
                     select (string)query2.Element("name") ).First(),
      Venue = ( from query3 in loadedData.Descendants("venue")
                where (int)query1.Element( "venueID" ) == (int)query3.Attribute("id")
                select (string)query3.Element("name") ).First(),
    };
```